# MySQL Left Join with Specific Condition

Tags: mysql

I have following tables that manage revenue

revenue Table

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| revenue_id | amount | status |
+------------+--------+--------+
|          1 |  45000 |      1 |
|          2 |  25000 |      1 |
|          3 |  67000 |      1 |
|          4 |  22000 |      1 |
|          5 |  32000 |      0 |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

bank Table

```
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| bank_id | ref_no | bank_amount | bank_status |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 |      2 |       23000 | Pending     |
|       2 |      3 |       67000 | Confirmed   |
|       3 |      4 |       22000 | Confirmed   |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

02) If a revenue as mentioned in the revenue table has banked, it is recorded in the bank table. After that, the amounts in two tables are equal, the bank status may be into "Confirmed".

03) So, I need to get Confirmed records only as following by joining above two tables

## Desired Output

```
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| revenue_id | amount | bank_amount | bank_status |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|          3 |  67000 |       67000 | Confirmed   |
|          4 |  22000 |       22000 | Confirmed   |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

## Desired Output-02

```
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| revenue_id | amount | bank_amount | bank_status |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|          1 |  45000 |             |             |
|          2 |  25000 |       23000 | Pending     |
|          3 |  67000 |       67000 | Confirmed   |
|          4 |  22000 |       22000 | Confirmed   |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

## Desired Output-03

```
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| revenue_id | amount | bank_amount | bank_status |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|          1 |  45000 |             |             |
|          2 |  25000 |       23000 | Pending     |
+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

04) To get the desired output I used the following query

```
select revenue.revenue_id, revenue.amount, bank.bank_amount, bank.bank_status 
from revenue
left join bank on bank.ref_no = revenue.revenue_id
where revenue.status = 1 and bank.bank_status = "Confirmed"
```

05) But did't get the expected result. It generated only the empty result. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can any one help me ?

Comment: Simply change to INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. But even with LEFT JOIN, you should not get empty results. There is something else wrong. Please provide a DB Fiddle showcasing it.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83fda8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Inner Join** instead of **Left JOIN** for your expected output.

```
SELECT revenue.revenue_id,
       revenue.amount,
       bank.bank_amount,
       bank.bank_status
FROM revenue
INNER JOIN bank ON bank.ref_no = revenue.revenue_id
WHERE revenue.status = 1
  AND bank.bank_status = "Confirmed"
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83fda8/1)**

Comment: @Sadihkasan. If I need to get output-02 as edited, What can be changed in your query. (Unbanked & Unconfirmed amounts should be included in the output-02)

Comment: SELECT revenue.revenue_id,
       revenue.amount,
       bank.bank_amount,
       bank.bank_status
FROM revenue
LEFT JOIN bank ON bank.ref_no = revenue.revenue_id
WHERE revenue.status = 1
ORDER BY revenue_id

Comment: @Sadihkasan. If I need to get output-03 as edited, What can be changed in your query. (Unbanked & Unconfirmed amounts only in the output-02)

Comment: Please try to google I cannot give answer as spoon feeding

Answer (score 0):

```
select revenue.revenue_id, revenue.amount, bank.bank_amount, bank.bank_status 
from revenue
Inner join (select * 
              From bank
              Where bank_status = "Confirmed") bank
on bank.ref_no = revenue.revenue_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the first bank table and then revenue table for left join .
Because in left join all rows will be returned even without matches.

So, use query like this.
select revenue.revenue_id, revenue.amount, bank.bank_amount, bank.bank_status 
from bank
left join revenue on bank.ref_no = revenue.revenue_id
where revenue.status = 1 and bank.bank_status = "Confirmed"